# How to prevent a Boolean value from being reset?

Tags: excel, vba, boolean

360 separate sheets make up this workbook.

The first sheet is the "Main Page," which is opened when the workbook is first opened, and has a userform that pops up containing the instructions for the main page.

For about 350 of the other sheets, there is a copy & pasted userform which contains instructions for those sheets, which all operate in the same manner.
Within those 350 userforms, there is a toggle button that flags a public variable as true, which prevents them from popping up again when the sheet is opened.

I want that toggle button to prevent those userforms from ever popping up again as long as the button is depressed on one of those pages.

```vb
If sheetOpenned = False Then
    SubPageInstructions.Show
End If
sheetOpenned = True
End Sub
```

sheetOpenned is the public boolean declared at the top of the page. Is there a way to make this flag as true for every page?

The public Boolean is reset when the workbook is closed.

How can I

1. prevent the public Boolean from being reset?
2. prevent the toggle button in my Userforms from being auto toggled to their default value on workbook close?

Comment: Store the variable in a cell on a worksheet, or in a defined name.  That will persist it across sessions.

Comment: @TImWilliams

Yes, that is the easy way out. But I want this to be handled in VBA. If there is no other way to do it, other than referring to a hidden cell in a sheet, then that is the route I will go.

I am just mightily annoyed by the fact that my values are force reset at the close of a session.

Comment: Is this Workbook always open by the same/unique user, at the same machine?

Comment: @ALeXceL Negative. This is being provided to a client for their own use, and once it is out of my hands, I have no idea how many people will be capable of opening it. I must assume it will be stored on a server, so it will not have simultaneous users editing it, if that means anything?

Comment: If positive, I would suggest you to save the state of each TB under the "VB and VBA Program Settings". The workbook_open event read it and, each action on a Toggle Button can be immediatly saved on that resource. But as @TimWilliams mentioned, the defined Name is, IMO, the adequate solution. The defined names values/settings can be handled by VBA.

Comment: Make the sheet suggested by Tim Williams very hidden if needed. If you want to go the hard way, you can create a .ini file that goes along with the macro or you may rewrite your code to look for your line of code, you may find how to do so [here](https://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Excel_VBproject_en.html). Other than those 3 options, I do not see another way of handling this.

Comment: @ALeXceL Interesting suggestion with the registry edit... Unfortunately, I don't think my clients will be capable of having their registries be edited by excel, as their IT department pretty much disables their ability to do anything but view files on their computers.

That leaves me with a named cell entry. That will suffice. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Anyway, no matter how many users are going to open the workbook, every user will have to see the Userform content at least once, right? So using the windows registry is still a good option. Another question: does the current user have to see each of the 350 userforms, or will it be enough to find out by looking at the first one? Are they all the same? This was not clear to me.

Comment: If they are allowed to run VBA macros, they have a 99.9% chance that they can manipulate the "VB & VBA Program Settings" registry subkeys by code.

Comment: @ALeXceL "Will it be enough to find out by looking at the first one..."

The main page Userform is unique, and then there's 350 duplicates on those individual sheets.

So, they will look at a total of (2) unique instruction userforms.

Comment: There are many places you can store a value in a workbook: 1) in a cell, as already mentioned.  2) in the registry, also already mentioned.  3) in  Name object (aka a Named Range, but they can refer to values too, not just ranges.  Can also be VeryHidden). 4) in a [document property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.customproperties). 5) in an XMLPart object. 6) in a file.

Comment: See [Custom xml parts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.customxmlparts)

Comment: @ALeXceL

Attempted to implement your solution. Please see comments below your answer, as I would appreciate your input.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I leave here the solution using the Windows Registry, registering the value of ToggleButton1 in it. In this example, I used a CommandButton, where the code evaluates whether there is a negation to display the Userform, written to the Registry. In the Userform itself, the code for registering the value of ToggleButton1 is saved, once clicked. The "VB & VBA Program Settings" subkey exists for each logged in user. So, for a new logged in user, the Userform will be displayed and, if the ToggleButton1 is clicked, it will be disabled for future reopenings of the Workbook.

### On the Userform code pane:

```
Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
    If Me.ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
        'don't show Me again.
        Me.ToggleButton1.Value = False
        fToggleButton1_State = False
        SaveSetting "My350Sheets", "SavedState", "ToggleButton1", False
    Else
        'uncomment the line below if you want the Userform to be shown again in the *NEXT* WB_open event
        'SaveSetting "My350Sheets", "SavedState", "ToggleButton1", True
    End If
End Sub
```

### On a standard Module code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Public fToggleButton1_State As Boolean
```

### On a CommandButton code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If fToggleButton1_State = True Then
        UserForm1.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: So I'm back at this following a weekend hiatus. I'm attempting to implement your registry solution, however, it seems to not be functioning in the desired mannerism. 

The Name for my ToggleButton is DisablePopup. 

Here is the code:

@ALeXceL

Comment: 'Private Sub DisablePopup_Click()
If Me.DisablePopup.Value = True Then
    'don't show Me again.
    Me.DisablePopup.Value = False
    fDisablePopup_State = False
    SaveSetting "My350Sheets", "SavedState", "DisablePopup", False
Else
    'uncomment the line below if you want the Userform to be shown again in the *NEXT* WB_open event
    SaveSetting "My350Sheets", "SavedState", "DisablePopup", True
End If
End Sub'

On the main page, there is the boolean value fDisablePopup_State

I have not used your Command Button.. as the button to bring up the instructions needs to -

Comment: - always work.

Please, for the love of god, inform me of how to format this code so that it displays properly, because I am clearly inept.

Comment: Best if we continue in a chat room: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/139026/windows-registry-vb-vba-program-settings?tab=general